# How do I add larger borders to shapes that have an already assigned size aesthetic in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot several features of a group of samples to various aesthetics. Border color and size of a circle is one of them. However, if I try to set a larger baseline border for these shapes, by setting `lwd=2`, the shapes all revert to the same size and the legend is gone. I just want the circles to have a larger border, how can I do this?

An example:

```
library(ggplot2)
testFrame <- data.frame(
  sizeVar=factor(c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b')),
  samples=rep(c('Sample1', 'Sample2'), times=4),
  features=c(rep('Feature1', times=4), rep('Feature2', times=4))
)
testPlot <- ggplot(data=testFrame, aes(x=samples, y=features))
testPlot + 
    geom_point(aes(size=sizeVar), pch=21, color='black', fill='gray') +
    scale_size_manual(values=c(9,4)) + theme_bw()
testPlot + 
   geom_point(aes(size=sizeVar), pch=21, lwd=3, color='black', fill='gray') + 
   scale_size_manual(values=c(9,4)) + theme_bw()
```

[image: Output without lwd]
[image]

Comment: It looks like a reproducible example, but it's not. Put in the code that creates `TestPlot`. Also look at the article in the most recent R Journal by Paul Murrell on labeling grid objects.

Comment: @DWin: [A link for the lazy](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-2/RJournal_2012-2_Murrell.pdf). Take a look in particular at Figure 7 on page 8.

Comment: My apologies, just edited in the code to create testPlot. Going over to lattice might be the way to go, but I would like to know if it can be done in ggplot2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with your graph:

```
> testPlot + 
    geom_point(aes(size=sizeVar), pch=21, color='black', fill='gray') +
    scale_size_manual(values=c(9,4)) + theme_bw()
```

List the elements:

```
> grid.ls()

GRID.gTableParent.162
  background.1-6-6-1
  spacer.4-3-4-3
  panel.3-4-3-4
    grill.gTree.126
      panel.background.rect.121
      panel.grid.major.y.polyline.123
      panel.grid.major.x.polyline.125
    geom_point.points.116
    panel.border.rect.118
  axis-l.3-3-3-3
    axis.line.y.zeroGrob.136
    axis
  axis-b.4-4-4-4
    axis.line.x.zeroGrob.130
    axis
  xlab.5-4-5-4
  ylab.3-2-3-2
  guide-box.3-5-3-5
  title.2-4-2-4
```

Now to change the appropriate element:

```
> grid.edit("geom_point.points", grep=TRUE, gp=gpar(lwd=3))
```

[image]

Comment: It feels a bit hacky but this works, although it will create a second page in a pdf device due to the redraw. I guess a work-around for that is to just plot it in an X11 device and do ggsave. Thanks!

Comment: Construct it outside the device call and then `print()` it within the device.

Comment: @DWin How exactly would you go about that? `grid.edit` doesn't enter into a `ggplot` object, so you can't `print` an object with its changes.

Comment: I think the only way to actually do it would be to construct in a `windows` or `X11` device and use `dev.copy` to copy it to pdf.